# how to repair charging system for laptop?

Tags: windows-10

My laptop's battery doesn't increase when it is turned on and charged but it increases when it is shut down. In the notification bar it shows (plugged in,not charging).how can i increase my laptop's battery while charging even if it is turned on?

Comment: Are you using the charger that came with the computer? Or one made by a third party? Sounds to me like the charging adapter does not have enough juice to drive both.

Comment: it is the one that came with the laptop. Not,its not made by the third party. charging adapter does not have enough juice to drive both, what does it mean?

Comment: As you can tell from the comment and answer, the nature of your problem isn't clear. If you run the battery down to a low level by using the laptop without the charger, will the battery charge while the laptop is powered on?  If you fully charge the battery while the laptop is powered off, do you get the expected run time operating from the battery, alone?  These questions will help to identify what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, *it's a feature, not a bug*.

Windows has a feature that is supposed to save the battery's life long term; it does not charge the battery continuously, but only if it goes below a certain threshold (or after a certain time).

So you might for many days see '94%, not charging', then '93%, not charging', etc. After some days, it should decide to charge back up to 100%; or when you run the machine on battery until it goes down to maybe 70%, it will start charging again.

Comment: but i want to increase my battery by charging even when my laptop is turned on. how can i do this ? plz suggest me the steps.